# Android Studio Git-merge won't end after resolve conflict

Tags: android, git, merge

Android Studio Git-merge won't end after resolve conflict.

I pulled code from remote to my local branch and there are some conflicts and android studio ask me to witch code wanna keep or merge. so I decide all my code and select "accept your" and there is many new files.

[image]

but merge won't end and new file won't come to my local change panel.  I also try this with  "accept-theirs" and the result was same.

[image]

I always do this and result was OK but I don't know how to manage this issue and why this happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funny think is i face this problem after 4 years with android studio 3.5.2. All conflicts are gone but it is also Merging signature as in question and also there is no commit! Because i expect a commit after merge.

The answer was so easy this time. I just open terminal and create a commit with bash like:

```
git commit -m "My message"
```

And it is done.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem when I left some merge issues unprocessed. For me **VCS -> GIT -> Resolve Conflicts**  helped.

Comment: Funny think is i face this problem after 4 years with android studio 3.5.2 .Resolve conflict is disabled.